# What is the name of this book?

Tags: motor, identification, electromagnetism, electromagnetic, books

I recently got a 2 page pdf document on double revolving field theory but I cant find the name of the book.
Can anyone identify this book?
[image]

Comment: Ask whoever gave you the PDF; I doubt anyone here will be able to recognise it.

Answer (score 8):

It is from "Induction and Synchronous Machines" by Murugesh Kumar
ISBN 9788125909262, 8125909265 (2000). Probably out of print.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.